# Detect weather user clicked on text or white space inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea that can be draged around in which text should still be selectable by draging over it. In order to distinguish a "over text drag" from a "move drag" I have to know weather the point where the user started its drag (i.e. mousedown position) was white space or text.

The only thing I can come up with to figure this out is calculating using character width and line height, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Maybe you can recreate the white space by putting a div under the textarea and remove the white space from the textarea (the space around the text)

Comment: Just add a drag handle.... what you want to do will fail on so many edge cases.

Comment: @epascarello you mean a resize handle? That would not be what I need

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking, but here's my attempt to translate the insanity into working code:

```js
let doc, htm, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
// magic under here
const test = I('test');
function whiteStart(string){
  if(string.match(/^\s+/)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
test.oncopy = test.ondragstart = function(){
  let s = getSelection().toString();
  if(whiteStart(s)){
    console.log('"'+s+'" starts with one or more white spaces');
  }
  else{
    console.log('"'+s+'" starts without a white space');
  }
}
}); // end load
```

```html
<div id='test'>I&apos;m just going to put some text in here so we can run a very basic test. I hope this helps!</div>
```

Comment: by "white space" (not "whitespace") i meant blank space, the part of a text where no characters are (e.g. to the right of a line that doesnt go to the very end).

Comment: `/^\s+/` is a RegExp for starting with one or more white spaces. What are you really trying to accomplish?